# reusing exported scheduled tasks on other machines. machine name is wrong for execution account

Tags: export, task-scheduler

I've got two scheduled tasks that I am reusing on 10 different machines which are not on a common domain. I exported the task and when I bring it in to another machine under the "Security Options" in the area that says "when running this task use this account" it has listed the wrong machinename. It is doing this because it takes the name of the machine the task is originally exported from.

On my handful of machines they always have the same local user account. But despite this I still must edit the raw xml of my task template to change the machine name to the proper one or the task will give me issues when I go to execute it.

How can I export a task and have it point to localhost or loopback instead of a hostname? I'm trying to avoid this extra xml edit step by using something generic that promotes re-usability.

I must be missing something. I like this export/import task mechanism but it seems out of place to have to edit xml nodes.

Answer (score 0):

Which OS?

If running Vista/2008 or better, then replace the machine name with a `.`; eg `.\accountname`.

Comment: Since the full stop works on sql server I thought it would work here too but it does not. Says that it is not a valid account name. Any other suggestions? http://s209.photobucket.com/albums/bb29/vegeta4ss/?action=view&current=taskscheduleerror.png